# How to call an asynchronous BPEL process?

Tags: web-services, oracle11g, soa, bpel

I've got an asynchronous BPEL process and I wanna call it from my Java EE web application. How can I do this? I'm using Oracle SOA-Suite 11g PS3.

Answer (score 0):

An Asynchronous SOAP/HTTP sender is basically the same as a Synchronous SOAP/HTTP client, just it throws away the response. Only check the HTTP status of the response to verify that the receiver understood your message.

An Asynchronous receiver is basically a SOAP/HTTP server listening on the address sent in the "ReplyTo/Adress" field of the request. After receiving the message it sends an empty response with a "200" status code.

The sent and received messages are correlated using the WS-Addressing SOAP header fields "MessageID" (request) and "RelatesTo" (response).

If you are happy with a "low-tech" solution, you can send/receive Asynch SOAP requests just as XML over HTTP. The following HTTP Request will be understood by the BPEL process "AsynchDummy" as an asynchronous request. AsynchDummy is the default asynchronous BPEL process generated with JDeveloper:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" env:encodingStyle="">
  <env:Header>
    <ReplyTo xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/addressing">
      <Address>http://localhost:3333/my/j2ee/servlet</Address>
      <PortType xmlns:ptns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/AsynchDummy">ptns:AsynchDummyCallback</PortType>
      <ServiceName xmlns:snns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/AsynchDummy">snns:AsynchDummyCallbackService</ServiceName>
    </ReplyTo>
    <MessageID xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/addressing" ans1:rootId="610005" xmlns:ans1="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel" ans1:parentId="160005" ans1:priority="0">ABC123</MessageID>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <AsynchDummyProcessRequest xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/AsynchDummy">
      <input>this is the request</input>
    </AsynchDummyProcessRequest>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Don't forget to set the SOAPAction HTTP header to **"initiate"** (including the quotation marks).

You can expect a similar message from the callback client step of the BPEL process:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Header xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:add="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/addressing" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <add:RelatesTo>ABC123</add:RelatesTo>
    <add:MessageID ans1:rootId="" ans1:parentId="" ans1:priority="0" xmlns:ans1="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel">ABC456</add:MessageID>
  </soap-env:Header>
  <soap-env:Body>
    <AsynchDummyProcessResponse xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/AsynchDummy">
      <result>this is the result</result>
    </AsynchDummyProcessResponse>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```